# Ошибка запуска apache и mariaDB в opensever

Tags: php, apache, mariadb

Не могу исправить ошибку запуска OpenServer. Windows 10 x64
[image: 1111]

[image: 2222]

Comment: Ищите в логах ошибки

Comment: что делали  с сервером, что запускаться перестал?

Comment: только установил его и сразу ошибку даёт